# san1 vs tai2 vs san1 tai2

Tags: cantonese

I am doing martial arts and met some Cantonese people.

In "Punch me to the body!" what word would I use for body? san1 (身), tai2 (體) or both? I found them all in the dictionary and I'm not sure which to use when. They speak very little English, so I thought I'd ask here. Also it would be nice to know how to say "Punch me to the body" or "punch me to the face" or "punch me here".

Comment: used online dictionaries yet？ iciba：用拳猛击，feed 用拳to  bkrs for more examples:用拳头打...的脊背(in the back),also 用拳头揍一 下背,用拳头打... 的脸(in ...'s face),also 用拳头向…脸上打去,go back to iciba, try "hit in body", 打在身上, suggestion: 用拳头打我（在身上）

Comment: I used Pleco, but it gives no information for when to use what word. Thanks for the tipps, I'll check them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, martial arts and Cantonese, you like Bruce Lee? Anyway, here's what you want:

打我心口 - punch (打) my (我) chest (心口)

打我個肚 - punch (打) my (我) abdomen (肚)

打我個頭 -  punch (打) my (我) head (頭)

打我呢度 -  punch (打) my (我) here (呢度) [supposed you pointed to somewhere by your finger, when you say it]

Sound files:

打　⋯　http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/daa2.Mp3

我　⋯　http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/ngo5.Mp3

心口　⋯　http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/sam1.Mp3 http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/hau2.Mp3

個肚　⋯　http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/go3.Mp3http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/tou5.Mp3

個頭　⋯　http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/go3.Mp3http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/tau4.Mp3

呢度　⋯　http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/nei1.Mp3http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/dou6.Mp3

Furthermore, 打 (punch) is assumed using fists. If you need other types of attacks (fingers, palm, elbow, or kick), you need to state clearly to you companions :)

BTW, just curious, which martial arts are you learning?

Comment: Hung4 gaa1 kyun4. A southern style. Thank you so much for your thorough answer. :-) Punch is perfect.